# .click() doesn't fire function?

Tags: jquery

I have checkboxes that toggle on/off select option values. This part works fine.

Now I want to "check" the check box after page load by default.

I tried `.click()` that checks the checkbox but doesn't run the click code that is linked to it. Tested on firefox 6.0.2, Safari & Chrome. Any suggestion how to do so?

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/radek/HExeK/1/) example is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/radek/HExeK/1/) or below

```
$(function(){

    $selectClone = $("select[name=db2_timestamp]").clone(true);
    $("input[name=hideit]").click(function(){
        var $this;
        $selectClone.find("option").attr("disabled", false);

        $("input[name=hideit]").each(function(){
            var value = $(this).attr('value');

            if($(this).is(":checked")){

                $selectClone.find("option").each(function(){
                    $this = $(this);
                    if($this.val().indexOf(value) != -1){
                        $this.attr("disabled", true);
                    }
                });
            }        
        })       

        var $select = $("select[name=db2_timestamp]")
        $select.children().remove();

        $selectClone.find("option:enabled").each(function(){
             $select.append($(this).clone(true));
         });
    });
    $("input[value=w]").click();
});
```

Comment: Oh I missed it, thanks for sharing the code

Comment: well, sometimes I wonder if I should add the code. What if jsfiddle doesn't work or doesn't exist anymore. Not sure what to do. Maybe create a question on meta :-)))))

Comment: Can't you just call the click code that is linked to it directly?

Comment: jsfiddle is perfect tool to share code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the hide/show bits into a function and call the function both in the click handler and in an initialize function. [Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/HExeK/25/)

Comment: @Radek No, not exactly. His code is calling the click function directly rather than breaking the hide/show functionality out into a separate function.

Comment: That's right, steveax's answer has a more complex code, +1 for that.

Comment: Yes, then the code is cleaner and more re-usable. Looks like your answer will be accepted.... Thank you.

Comment: Implemented your solution. Thank you.

Comment: For some reason, and admittedly I don't see why, I can't get this code to display all three options.

Answer (score 0):

Um... works for me on Safari 5.0.4.  I suspect that on whatever browser you are running, .click() doesn't work for checkboxes for some reason.  Try running the code on change as well, maybe.

Comment: Ah.. yeah `click` is the wrong thing to run on load, since nothing is being 'clicked'.  Try writing a bit of script to look at the checkboxes on load and run the code "manually".

Comment: Nothing is being clicked but the checkbox is clicked. It doesn't make much sense to me...

Comment: The checkbox is `checked`.  "Click" fires on a specific human action, pushing down the mouse button.  The checkbox loading checked, then, doesn't fire any special events (because nothing is *happening*, it just starts that way).

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to call your function separately.

The following should work:

```
$(function(){

  $selectClone = $("select[name=db2_timestamp]").clone(true);
  var $click = function(){
    var $this;
    $selectClone.find("option").attr("disabled", false);

    $("input[name=hideit]").each(function(){
        var value = $(this).attr('value');

        if($(this).is(":checked")){

            $selectClone.find("option").each(function(){
                $this = $(this);
                if($this.val().indexOf(value) != -1){
                    $this.attr("disabled", true);
                }
            });
        }        
    })       

    var $select = $("select[name=db2_timestamp]")
    $select.children().remove();

    $selectClone.find("option:enabled").each(function(){
         $select.append($(this).clone(true));
     });
  };
  $("input[name=hideit]").click($click);
  $("input[value=w]").click();
  $click();
});
```

[Here's a working jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RHkQK/)

Comment: To be honest I would remove the possibility to downvote. How can somebody downvote working answer???????????

Comment: Actually, the downvote serves the purpose of filtering the working answers from the rest. I don't mind being downvoted, but I do mind when there is no apparent reason for it. I hope this answer helps btw.

Comment: Yet, it doesn't mean it's not.

Comment: @Gabe: could you elaborate on that?

Comment: @Radek: I believe what he means, or meant, since he deleted his comment, is that maybe there's a better, working answer.

Comment: That makes sense :-) But at the time you posted your answer there was nothing better. I believe that somebody downvoted it without even trying your fiddle... Anyway... Thank you for your effort.

Comment: You end up running $click() twice on the initial load.  Once when you fire the .click() event, and once when you call $click() directly.  This works, but instead of firing the click event you can set the checked property directly and avoid running that method twice.

Answer (score 0):

Your click function is getting called, but when it runs the checkbox has not been checked yet.  This can be confirmed with an alert at the top of your click function.

The problem is that your click function is running before Firefox actually checks the box, so your selector that finds the ":checked" inputs does not yet include the checkbox you triggered.

There are a number of ways you could fix this, either of these should get you started:
1. setting the checked property within your click function
2. only work with the checkbox that was clicked, not each checkbox

Comment: Any chance you can elaborate on these two ways. I do not understand. #1 why would I set checked property? It was already set, wasn't it. #2 how can this help?

Answer (score 0):

When you call the click() method, it seems to be running the Javascript methods bound to that event before actually setting the checked property.  I believe this is the root of the problem in your initial post.

By setting the checked property manually first, then running the standard callback associated with a click event, we can mimic the standard behavior.  I've written this code out and [posted it in this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qu9mH/).  I also cleaned up the code a bit and made it so the select box retains the selected option when other options are shown or hidden.